# Retrieve Trash size as an int in cocoa app

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nstask, recycle-bin

Is it possible for a cocoa app to retrieve the size of the trash as an int. Is `NSTask` the correct method to do this?

Comment: Total number of bytes occupied. Eg. Trash Size: 25MB

Answer (score 3):

There's no easy way to do this. Although the Mac GUI presents a unified Trash, there's not just one thing which is the trash. Each volume can have a separate trash and volumes can come and go.

Also, it can be quite time-consuming to calculate the size of the contents of a folder, so this doesn't seem like a very good idea.

If you really want to do it, you'd enumerate all of the mounted volumes using something like `-[NSFileManager mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:options:]`, convert the URLs to `FSRef`s using `CFURLGetFSRef()`, get a volume reference number from the `FSRef` using `FSGetCatalogInfo()` passing `kFSCatInfoVolume` for `whichInfo`, find the Trash for each volume using `FSFindFolder()` passing `kTrashFolderType` for `folderType`, convert the resulting `FSRef` to a URL using `CFURLCreateFromFSRef()`, create a directory enumerator for that URL using `-[NSFileManager enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:` passing `NSURLTotalFileAllocatedSizeKey` in the `keys` array, enumerate through that enumerator getting each item's `NSURLTotalFileAllocatedSizeKey` as an `NSNumber`, and accumulating the `-unsignedLongLongValue`s of those `NSNumber`s.

It may actually be easier to enumerate the volumes using `FSGetVolumeInfo()`, passing `kFSInvalidVolumeRefNum` for `volume` and an index, starting at 1, for `volumeIndex`. You'd also pass `kFSVolInfoNone` for `whichInfo`. You'd increment the index and repeat until it returns `nsvErr`. The advantage is that this gives you the volume reference number directly so you don't have to go from URL to `FSRef` to volume reference number. The disadvantage is that this is one more old-style API. However, you have no choice but to use those APIs because there's no substitute for `FSFindFolder()` in the above.

Anyway, as you enumerate over the volumes get their trash folders, you have to be prepared to encounter volumes which don't have trash folders. For example, network-mounted volumes often don't.